# Creating a linked list from a binary tree (preorder tranversal)

Tags: c, linked-list, binary-tree, preorder

So I'm trying to create a linked list from a binary tree using preorder tranversal.
I'm having so many problems at doing it, I saw some of  the "solutions" but I didn't like it! I am trying something simple.

This is the code that I got until now:

```
typedef struct nodo {
  int value;
  struct nodo *left, *right;
} *ABin;

typedef struct lligada { 
  int value;
  struct lligada *next;
} *LInt;

void preorder (ABin a, LInt * l) {

  LInt r=*l,tmp;
  tmp=r;

  if (!a) {
    *l=NULL;
}
  else {
    r=malloc(sizeof(struct lligada));
    r->value=a->value;
    r=r->next;
    *l=tmp;
    preorder (a->left,l);
    preorder (a->right,l);
  }
}
```

I'm getting always an empty list!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> > if (!a) { *l=NULL; }

This will allways be the last thing done in your function, with the null in *l being passed all the way up.

The rest also has problems:

> > r=r->next;

But you never set `r->next` to anything. You'll have to do that first.

Further, when you first call `preorder()` what, if anything, is `*l` pointing to?   You'd probably be better off, instead of passing in a LInt*, having the function return a Lint*  (joining the lists after the internal calls to `preorder()`)

Comment: I would love to, but I can't change the declaration. It was implemented by my teacher.

Comment: `void preorder(ABin a, LInt *l) { LInt b = correct_preorder(a); *l = b; }`  Then code `correct_preorder()` similar to your code.